# Making map in Robinson or Winkel Tripel projection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to make a map like this: 
https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/coordinate_reference_systems.html#figure-robinson-projection

I have downloaded a shapefile with world borders from here: 
http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php

This looks fine with the WGS 84 projection. [image: WGS 84]

However, when I select the Winkel Tripel or the Robinson projection (both world and sphere), I get an artifact in Russia.

[image: World_Robinson]

How can this be prevented?

I have located similar problems, but they are trying to project earth from space, which I am not, and therefore the solution does not seem to be applicable here.

Edit: 
I have found one solution which is visually ok. I removed the part of the polygon that reached the edge of the map, on both sides. Mathematichally this is less than ideal of course.

Comment: Could be caused by the polygon crossing 180° meridian. There is an answer here somewhere regarding this issue, but cannot find it atm. Try split in two parts.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! I think @MrXsquared is right - [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/175649/55203) might help.